# When I use iMessages, is a copy of all messages retained in iCloud?

Tags: icloud, messages

When I use iMessages, is a copy of all messages retained in iCloud (on Apple's servers)? If yes, how can I delete them?

Comment: Since I don't have a source to quote i will make this a comment, but only undelivered iMessages are stored by iMessage servers.  Any other implementation and apple would go bankrupt complying with subpoenas.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud does store copies of your iMessages with the backup of the iDevices. To delete them, you'd have to delete every iCloud-Backup that contains the message.

As to my knowledge, there is no user-accessible copy of the iMessage stored apart from the backups.